# Pine Script order.entry/close off by a day

Tags: pine-script

I've created a small strategy that does an order entry when price crosses over an offset VWAP (and closes when price crosses under).

The issue I'm seeing is that the order and exit is off buy 1 increment and I'm not sure why exactly.  I've used 'plotshape' to show the after crossovers, and they're always right before the actual order entry/closes.  Any idea what I'm missing here?:

```
strategy("VWAP Crossover", overlay=true)

price = input(type=input.source, defval=ohlc4, title="source")
vwapFunction = vwap(price)[3]

crossing_over = crossover(close,vwapFunction)
crossing_under = crossunder(close,vwapFunction)

plot(vwapFunction, title="VWAP", color=color.white, linewidth=2, transp=0, editable=true)
plotshape(series=crossing_over, title="Long", style=shape.triangleup, color=#7FFF33)
plotshape(series=crossing_under, title="Long", style=shape.triangledown, color=#FF746E)

if (crossing_over)
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long,1)
if (crossing_under)
    strategy.close("Buy")
```

Answer (score 1):

By default strategies only calculate on every bar close, and enter the position on what would logically be the next tick, the next bar's open.

For historical bars, you have no option but to calculate on the bar's close, as tradingview does not have historical tick data. For realtime bars, there is an option to set the strategy to calculate on every tick, but I would not recommend using it unless you understand the logic of it. In order to get results that are congruent with backtesting, you must execute on confirmed data. For example, if you take your plotshape and put it on an indicator, or set the strategy to calc on every tick, you will see the shape flicker in and out when watching it cross live. How would your strategy behave if it was buying every tick that the plotshape appeared, as it could disappear and reappear many times per bar?

Essentially if you were using an indicator to control live trading, you would only want to use the last bar's confirmed data when making decisions. The strategy tester just takes care of this for you.

So basically, the gap is one tick, instead of executing on the bar's close, you are executing on the next bar's open. To make your plotshapes match you could simply add a `[1]` to the series.

There is an option to set `process_orders_on_close=true` in the strategy function, but I wouldn't recommend it unless you have a good reason to use it. I don't know enough about tick frequency and their implementation to know for sure, but it either:
A. Constantly keeps track of time with a high degree of accuracy to determine whether it is impossible for the next tick to occur in the same bar, thus saving you the amount of time between the cutoff point and the next tick. Or
B. Calculates on historical data using the last tick when it would not have known in realtime whether the tick was the last. Or
C. A combination thereof.

For starting out, assuming that the one tick isn't going to negate your strategy's efficacy, I would leave it at the default settings.

Note this is also why you will see a lot of people mentioning repainting when talking about indicators, your decisions must be made on confirmed data for past data to align with live data. Repainting in one sense refers to the flickering you will see when you have a plotshape on a moving average crossover.

Edit: Since I reread and saw that you mentioned it being off by a day, you might consider reworking your strategy to operate on a smaller timeframe. As the tick between two days could matter a lot more on regular stock markets.

Comment: process_orders_on_close=true was exactly what I was after.  Thanks very much.